# Why do I get this error while running django project even after adding mysql to settings?

Tags: django, python-3.x, mysql-python

When I try to run the django project, I get this error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems like a database error. Your database is set to use `caching_sha2_password` as an authentication plugin. You need to change it from your mysql config.

In your mysql configuration file, you may want to change `default_authentication_plugin` parameter:

```
[mysqld]

default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

You need to restart mysql server to make this change active.

Also you may change it by user with the following sql statement:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

---

If you do not depend on mysql you can change database engine to sqlite and run the project. If there is no coding error, it should run smoothly. After solving mysql issue you can switch back to mysql backend.